# apache shuts down for no reason

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http

I am a little baffled here. I am using `CentOs 5 64bit` and `directadmin`. I am also running `Apache 2.2.19`. I was pulling my hair out because some of my uploads were stopping and becoming incomplete for no reason and now after seeing my php_error_log is empty, I checked my apache log for all the errors that occurred near the mishap and got this

```
[Fri Jul 08 00:10:02 2011] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using server1.mywebsite.com for ServerName
[Fri Jul 08 00:10:03 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Jul 08 00:10:03 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 08 00:11:01 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Jul 08 00:11:02 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Jul 08 00:11:02 2011] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Jul 08 00:11:03 2011] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `localhost' does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Jul 08 00:11:03 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.19 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

It seems my server shut down for no reason (SIGHUP received. SIGTERM etc.). What is going on here? Should I put up a firewall? Could this be malicious?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Logrotate or some other similar application? Logrotate will restart applications that it writes logs too.

Comment: Not usually at that time though.

Comment: I am on a default directadmin installation and I do not see logrotate anywhere. I do not believe I am running it. Should I change any port options? I am going to run acunetix on my site. HEYYY Ignacio, we meet again!

Comment: +1 - if not logrotate, some other cron job?  Not likely a coincidence that it happened at almost exactly 10 minutes after midnight.